# Netbeans is there a way to manualy complile all .less files in one directory (which has subdirectories)

Tags: netbeans

I have a dir where are lots of subdirs and inside those are .less files, until today my settings were "compile on save" so if i changed some .less files netbeans would automatically compile them on save, but now i'm looking for a functionality to recompile all .less files in a dir even if some weren't changed, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Grunt task to that (and invoke the task from IDE assuming you have 8.0 and higher) or maybe try to disable Less compilation in NetBeans, close the project properties dialog and enable it again. It could trigger compilation.

Comment: Thanks, disabling and enabling less compilation triggered compilation, if there is no other way to trigger it, it will be fine :)